# Android: Get the IP address of a server name in Local Area Network

Tags: java, android, network-programming, lan

Does anyone know how to find IP address of a server using the server name? I have tried the following:

```
InetAddress[] addresses =  InetAddress.getAllByName(serverName);
```

and

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(serverName);
```

Both thrown ***UnknownHostException*** if the name of the server is my server connected locally (eg. server name "TestServer"). However, if I pass in: **www.google.com**, it worked! It only fail when I tried to find server (that is connected locally) using the server name.

Any idea?

Thanks

---

Note: I have set the permission in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: can use the method InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

Comment: so did you got the localhost info?

Comment: Hi Debo, correct me if I wrong, but I think InetAddress.getLocalHost(); just get the current device info? I need to get the server IP. For example, I am using my phone and would like to get IP address of Windows computer named "TestServer". Something like ***ping TestServer*** in Windows machine where it can find the IP address of other computer.

Comment: For what do you need that ip address?

Comment: show what you got in `serverName` variable

Comment: @greenapps, I need it to connect to the server using socket (the server is written in C# as Windows Service). In order to do that, I need to know the IP address.

Comment: @VladMatvienko, **serverName** will be the name of the server for example ***InetAddress.getByName("TestServer");***

Comment: `TestServer` might not be something known by the network (DNS). `InetAddress.getByName` queries DNS server to give IP of the server by the DNS name. So is you server written in your DNS as a `TestServer`?

Comment: The Android client can just try to connect to ip adresses around its own ip address.  The ip of the server will not differ much if they are in the same network. Within seconds the client will have found the right server.

Comment: @greenapps, the problem is, I know the server name, but not the IP address. Futhermore the IP address "***might***" changed (although not likely). And plus, it is easier for the user to remember the server name rather than remember the IP address.

Comment: You did not understand a word of what i said. Please reread. The user does not have to remember anything. Or type in an ip. And it does not matter if the ip of the server or client changes. You just have to write some code.

Comment: @greenapps, oh, I apologize. you are right. sorry. How can I archive this?

Comment: Well i already told you what you should code. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @Sam can you tell me what is the address of your local server?Can check it then and give you the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("ServerName");
String serverName= addr.getHostName();
Log.e("ServerName",serverName);
```

You must set your network DNS in your device like this

[image]

Or Set programmatically :

Add permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Change DNS :

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_DNS1, "192.168.0.5");
android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_DNS2, "192.168.0.2");
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad, I need the other way around. I need to get the IP address of the particular computer. For example ***InetAddress.getByName("TestServer");***, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Ahmad, where do you get the value of DNS1 and DNS2 value? I used my server value which is ***192.168.1.1*** and I have only 1 IP for both DNS. I tried it, but it still fails...

Comment: Hmmm... I wonder if this is a firewall thing. But using C# code to get the IP address works fine. Let me investigate further and get back to you. Thanks you so so much!

Comment: Hi @Sam did you ever got a solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: No, I haven't find solution for this :(